# c# find 2 values in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have 7 options in my programm, and I want after I change 2 array values ,program do other options. 
This is my array

```
string[] map = {"0","0","0","0","0","0","0"};
```

And for example I have in my picturebox click these lines

```
void PictureBox1Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(map[0] == "0"){map[0] = "B";}
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("../Debug/images/changed-image.png");
}
```

And at the end ,when I click 2 of my 7 picturebox ,array can look like this

```
string[] map = {"B","0","0","0","B","0","0"};
```

After these 2 changes ,I want to user can select other 2 options ,but now to picture box show other images ,like **green-change-image**

Im new in C# ,that's why I look for answer there.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you whant... improve your question.

Comment: @Gusman sorry ,but English not my native language :(

Comment: Yes, i understand, but we can't know what you need like that...

Comment: @Gusman I want to make C# programm like this [link]https://csgomapveto.com - user ban 2 maps after that user pick 2 maps and third map choose by random. test this website and I think you get what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after seeing the web I belive I understand what you want, and I would change a lot the logic:

1-Create 5 picture boxes (as you should have) and store in the Tag property the map name.

2-Create a List mapChoices = new List(); in the form definition.

3-On the click of the picture boxes use this:

```
void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string theMap = (sender as PictureBox).Tag.ToString();

    if(mapChoices.Count > 3 || mapChoices.Contains(theMap))
       return;

    mapChoices.Add(theMap);

    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("../Debug/images/changed-image.png");
}
```

After 4 clicks it will let you a list of four maps, the two first are the banned ones and the third and second the selected ones.

Comment: oh. Im new in C# ,knew only simple things. I have 7 picture boxes. and I dont know where to put something. maybe we can discuss this more easier than this website? and maybe I understand you better :)

Comment: I've tried to join you to a stackoverflow chat but you don't have enough reputation...

Comment: maybe some other place to discuss? skype e.tc.

Comment: I'm not very fan of posting my email in a SO comment...

Comment: maybe some social network?

Comment: Tell you the one and how to connect :D

Comment: Sent hangouts invitation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have understood you correctly, but if I have, you could always count the number of times a "B" character appears in your map array and act accordingly. For example:

```
void PictureBox1Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    int i, times=0;        
    for (i=0;i<7;i++)
        if (map[i]=="B")
            times++;
    if(map[0] == "0"){map[0] = "B";}
    if (times<2)
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("../Debug/images/changed_image.png");
    else
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("../Debug/images/another_changed-image.png");
}
```